# Use one login Server throw different sites

Tags: symfony

I have several Sites ( Apps ) and I want to share the users from one to another. For example, I want a user in a Calendar APP, to create Posts in another Site. But not having two diferent users in the two different Sites.
I've tried with [FOSOAuthServerBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle) But I always need to pass through an external page to authenticate and aprove the App. I just one the page1.com/login and page2.com/login, to resolve to the same users. But I think, sharing the database is dirty as hell.

Comment: This really depends a lot on your overall infrastructure. Do these Apps share the same server? The same code base? The same programming language? Are these Apps bundles in one big symfony application?

Comment: All Apps Share Programming Language (PHP) and also Framework( Symfony2), right now are in the same server, but, it will change in short term. I've tried aldo HWIOauthBundle for the Client Side, by I wasn't able to create a "Transparent" login with it.

Comment: If they are not sharing the same server, you will probably not have another option than using some sort of single sign on (SSO). OAuth is one possibility, but you could also have a look at OpenID or Facebook Connect. Also check this answer: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/86115/alternatives-to-oauth